Spring Batch Service: UnsatisfiedDependencyException when extends DefaultBatchConfiguration
I appreciate your help to find the cause of the exception listed below thrown when attempted to extend the DefaultBatchConfiguration. The Spring Batch Service show below works fine when doesn't extend the "Default  Batch Configuration". I new in the Spring Batch Service, I am training by following the spring tutorial in this link "https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing#header" for creating a Batch Service. It will be a big help if someone from the StakeOverflow community explains how to configure Spring Batch Service when extends DefaultBatchConfiguration, the objective is to fix the problem and make a solid my understand how to extend the Default Batch Configuration.
Implementation detail:

Uses SpringBootApplication to run the job
Uses two databases

MySQL as job repository
PostgreSQL as data


Project Maven
IDE Eclipse

Libraries used and version:

Java JDK version 22
Spring Batch version 5.1.2
Spring Boot version 5.1.2
PostgreSQL version 42.7.2
MySQL Connector version 8.0.33

Debug Log:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v3.2.10)

2024-11-05T14:30:17.788-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.e.b.BatchProcessingApplication         : Starting BatchProcessingApplication using Java 22 with PID 2912 (D:\User\Gilmar\git-repo\spring-batch-mastery\spring-batch-initial\target\classes started by Gilmar in D:\User\Gilmar\git-repo\spring-batch-mastery\spring-batch-initial)
2024-11-05T14:30:17.790-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.e.b.BatchProcessingApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-11-05T14:30:18.464-05:00  WARN 2912 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'batchConfiguration' of type [com.example.batchprocessing.BatchConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
2024-11-05T14:30:18.488-05:00  WARN 2912 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jobRegistry' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-11-05T14:30:18.562-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-11-05T14:30:19.026-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@6778aea6
2024-11-05T14:30:19.028-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-11-05T14:30:19.061-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.e.batchprocessing.BatchConfiguration   : ******jobTemplate running******
2024-11-05T14:30:19.078-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.e.batchprocessing.BatchConfiguration   : ******FlatFileItemReader******
2024-11-05T14:30:19.095-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.e.batchprocessing.BatchConfiguration   : ******PersonItemProcessor******
2024-11-05T14:30:19.096-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.e.batchprocessing.BatchConfiguration   : ******JdbcBatchItemWriter******
2024-11-05T14:30:19.118-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
2024-11-05T14:30:19.145-05:00  WARN 2912 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'importUserJob' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'importUserJob' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'step1' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to configure the default job repository
2024-11-05T14:30:19.147-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-11-05T14:30:19.196-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-11-05T14:30:19.220-05:00  INFO 2912 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-11-05T14:30:19.249-05:00 ERROR 2912 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'importUserJob' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'importUserJob' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'step1' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to configure the default job repository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchProcessingApplication.main(BatchProcessingApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'step1' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to configure the default job repository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [com/example/batchprocessing/BatchConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to configure the default job repository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to configure the default job repository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: Unable to configure the default job repository
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultBatchConfiguration.jobRepository(DefaultBatchConfiguration.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$jobRepository$29(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:348) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.jobRepository(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException:  To use the default configuration, a data source bean named 'dataSource' should be defined in the application context but none was found. Override getDataSource() to provide the data source to use for Batch meta-data.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultBatchConfiguration.getDataSource(DefaultBatchConfiguration.java:250) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultBatchConfiguration.jobRepository(DefaultBatchConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    ... 55 common frames omitted

------Code------
@SpringBootApplication
public class BatchProcessingApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(BatchProcessingApplication.class, args)));
    }
}

@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {
//public class BatchConfiguration {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);
    
    @Bean("jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate( @Qualifier("pgDataSource")DataSource dataSource) {
        log.info("******jobTemplate running******");
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    
    @Bean("reader")
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        log.info("******FlatFileItemReader******");
      return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
        .name("personItemReader")
        .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
        .delimited()
        .delimiter(",")
        .names("firstName", "lastName")
        .targetType(Person.class)
        .build();
    }
    @Bean("processor")
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
      log.info("******PersonItemProcessor******");
      return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean("writer")
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer( @Qualifier("pgDataSource") DataSource dataRepository) {
        log.info("******JdbcBatchItemWriter******");
      return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
        .sql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)")
        .dataSource(dataRepository)
        .beanMapped()
        .build();
    }
    
    @Bean("importUserJob")
    public Job importUserJob(@Qualifier(
            "mySQLJobRepository")JobRepository jobRepository,
            Step step1,
            JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        
        log.info("******importUserJob******");
        return new JobBuilder("importUserJob", jobRepository)
            .listener(listener)
            .start(step1)
            .build();
    }
    @Bean("step1")
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository,  
            DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager,
            @Qualifier("reader")FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader,
            @Qualifier("processor")PersonItemProcessor processor,
            @Qualifier("writer")JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        
        log.info("******step1******");
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
        .<Person, Person> chunk(3, transactionManager)
        .reader(reader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(writer)
        .build();
    }
    
    /***** Spring Batch Data sources and Job Repository*****/
    /**
     * This method created a Job repository 
     * @param mySQLDataSource contains the dataSource object to create a Job Repository
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean("mySQLJobRepository")
    public JobRepository jobRepository(DataSource mySQLDataSource) throws Exception {
    
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(mySQLDataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(new DataSourceTransactionManager(mySQLDataSource));
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE");
        factory.setMaxVarCharLength(255);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        
        return factory.getObject();
    }
    /**
     * This method creates a data source based on properties settings in the   *"application.properties" to manage the MySQL database to use as the Job Repository.
     * 
     * @return a data source object
     * 
     * Note:
     *    The @ConfigurationProperty @Value annotations are redundant for training purposes, just one is good enough.
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean("mySQLDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db.job.repo")
    public DataSource mySQLDataSource(
            @Value("${db.job.repo.driverClassName}") String className,
            @Value("${db.job.repo.jdbc-url}") String url,
            @Value("${db.job.repo.username}") String userName,
            @Value("${db.job.repo.schema}") String password) {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .driverClassName(className)
                .url(url)
                .username(userName)
                .password(password)
                .build();
    }
        
    /**
     * This method creates a data source based on the properties settings in the "application.properties" to manage the PostgreSQL database to use as data repository.
     * @return dataSource object created
     * 
     * Note:
     *    The @ConfigurationProperty @Value annotations are redundant for training purposes, just one is good enough.  
     */
    @Bean("pgDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db.src")
    public DataSource pgDataRepository(
            @Value("${db.src.driverClassName}") String className,
            @Value("${db.src.jdbc-url}") String url, 
            @Value("${db.src.username}") String userName,
            @Value("${db.src.password}") String password) {
        
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .driverClassName(className)
                .url(url).username(userName)
                .password(password)
                .build();
    }
}

@Component
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    /**
     * Constructor - It will allows to create an object/instance of JdbcTemplate because spring data jdbc on on the JAVA Library path
     * @param jdbcTemplate
     */
    public JobCompletionNotificationListener(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
          }

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        JobExecutionListener.super.beforeJob(jobExecution);
        log.info("Job {} started", jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        JobExecutionListener.super.afterJob(jobExecution);
        log.info("Job {} end", jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName());
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            log.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results");

            jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM people", new DataClassRowMapper<>(Person.class))
                    .forEach(person -> log.info("Found - first name, last name ( {},{}) in the database.", person.firstName(),person.lastName() ));
        }
    }
}

public record Person(String firstName, String lastName) {}

public class PersonItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Person, Person> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonItemProcessor.class);
    
    @Override
    public Person process(final Person person) {
        final String firstName = person.firstName().toUpperCase();
        final String lastName = person.lastName().toUpperCase();
        
        final Person transformedPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName);
        
        log.info("Converting (" + person + ") into (" + transformedPerson + ")");

        return transformedPerson;
    }
}

src/main/resource
***application.properties***

db.job.repo.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.job.repo.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batch-initial?currentSchema=batch-initial
db.job.repo.username=****
db.job.repo.password=*****
db.job.repo.schema=batch-initial
# Whether to populate schema for Spring Batch in case it's absent
#batch.db.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
db.job.repo.initialize-schema=ALWAYS

db.src.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/SPRINGBATCH?currentSchema=batch-initial
db.src.username=******
db.src.password=******
db.src.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

***data.sql***

DROP TABLE people IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE people  (
 --   id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    person_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20)
);

***sample-data.txt***

Jill,Doe
Joe,Doe
Justin,Doe
Jane,Doe
John,Doe

File pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>batchprocessing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Batch Service</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I expected to extend the DefauldBatchConfiguration when configure a Spring Batch Service


Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException:  To use the default configuration, a data source bean named 'dataSource' should be defined in the application context but none was found. Override getDataSource() to provide the data source to use for Batch meta-data.

As this error message explains, you need to define a datasource named "dataSource", or override DefaultBatchConfiguration#getDataSource() to provide the data source to use for Batch meta-data.

Thanks Mahmoud for the answer,
It works when I defined the "dataSource" by renamed the bean name from "mySQLDataSource" to "dataSource" and use as Qualifier in the job repository. It means the exception went away the spring batch is running.

By the way, I note if using the DefaultBatchConfiguration then overwrite specific configuration that works without DefaultBatchConfiguration for example in the step was set to ". allowStartIfComplete (true)" because I want to force the job fully execute every time, runs for train purpose, but it doesn't run after extended the "DefaultBatchConfiguration" because the previous run status was COMPLETED.

I would like to know more in terms of background whether or not I should use the DefaultBatchConfiguration.  When should I use? What is the mindset to use? What methods may need to override.

DefaultBatchConfiguration is really meant to provide some sensible defaults for batch infrastructure. It is not mandatory to use it at all. The fact that the job does not restart because it is completed is by design and not related to the way you configure spring batch (ie with or without using the DBC class)
